# Another name for a cheval de frise

Tags: expressions, translation, french

I need another way to label a *cheval de frise* for my book. The problem is, the story takes place in a fantasy setting that neither contains the French language, nor Frisians.

Comment: Most likely the reason you'll find ***cheval-de-frise*** in *English* dictionaries is *we don't have a word for it*. Are you going to avoid all Latin-derived words in your story, if the Roman Empire never existed within the fictional setting?

Comment: So call it a *horse-thorn hedge* (can't call it a *fence*, that's got French roots too).

Comment: My dictionary suggests "portable obstacle".

Comment: If your fantasy setting does not contain the French language, it does not contain the English language. English is just German with no grammar and French vocabulary. Luckily, precisely because it's a fantasy setting, you're not limited to stealing words from the French. Nobody says you can't borrow *cheval-de-frise* from Ukrainian or Japanese instead. Or the completely made up nation of Chnerf. Or you could just coin a word all of your own, you know.

Comment: @GEdgar very funny. (Though for the benefit of others maybe we do have to spell out that both *portable* and *obstacle* are French words as well.)

Comment: Thanks for the excellent feedback. I’m not concerned with derivative vocabulary, rather transparent cross over, so words like fence or sable isn’t an issue. I really like “horse-thorn barricade”. That’s pure genius. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The English for "cheval-de-frise" is "cheval-de-frise". See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cheval-de-frise.

From “Crusade of the Excelsior” By Bret Harte

> At its lower extremity a tall hedge of cactus reinforced the crumbling wall with a cheval de frise of bristling thorns; it was through a gap in this green barrier that he had found his way a few hours before, as his torn clothes still testified. 
>   http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2471/2471-h/2471-h.htm

The vocabulary of the military was often borrowed from French (or Norman French) as historically it had been the Norman army that had conquered England and built castles, etc. and thereafter French speaking nobles who ruled, raised armies, and administered.

Army, soldier, cannon, cavalry, canon, mote; bailey, keep; castle; fort; trench, battle, battlement, portcullis, rampart, charge, attack, etc are all of French derivation or borrowed directly.